# Ruby: Make hash from Hash => Set

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, set

I have a join table that I'm using to find available services for an order form; in that table is the `utility_id` and a `company_id`.

What I want is a group (hash) where the keys are the utility names and the values are hashes of the corresponding companies.

I got the following...

```
Service.find(:all).to_set.classify { |service| Utility.find(service.utility_id).name }
```

... which very nicely gives me a hash where the keys are the utility names, but the values are **Set**s of the Service records, not just the company names (I don't need the actual records), and I can't figure out how I'd make the hash I want:

```
# example of what I would like to have
{"electricity" => {"conEd" => 1, "Dominian" => 2}, "gas" => {"conEd" => 1}} 
# where the key is Utility.name, and the value-hash is {Company.name => Company.id}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: I'm confused about where "company-1" comes from. If it's just a numeric sequence, wouldn't you rather have an array as each hash value? So: `{"utility-1" => [company_id, company_id], "utility-2" => [company_id, company_id]}`

Comment: Sorry; I meant that a "company-1" was just the name of one company as separate from another "company-2", not that they were actually incrementing values.  Edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find(:all)` suggests Rails to me, so assuming you have a HABTM between the Utility and Service models correctly, this snippet works for my test environment:

```
results = Hash.new
Utility.find(:all).each do |utility|
  results[utility.name] = Hash.new
  utility.companies.each do |company|
    results[utility.name][company.name] = company.id
  end
end
results
```

Which produces

```
{"Communications"=>{"InternetCo"=>2, "PhoneCo"=>1}, "Energy"=>{"ElectricCo"=>4, "GasCo"=>3, "OilCo"=>5}}
```

Comment: The HABTM relationship (I'm using has_many, :through) is actually between `Company` and `Utility`; `Service` is my join model. And yes, I am using Rails (forgot to mention that). How would I change what you wrote above to work with my setup?

Comment: Edited to conform to your model objects.